# How to prove this SNR-like function is concave?

Tags: optimization, convex-analysis

I have this equation, which is similar to SINR somehow but the covariance matrix is a function of vector $\mathbf s$ with length of $M$
$$SINR = \mathbf s^HC^{-1}(\mathbf s)\mathbf s $$ 
where
$$C(\mathbf s) = S(\mathbf s)WS(\mathbf s) + N $$
and $ S(\mathbf s) $ is covolution matrix of $\mathbf s$.
In simulations, it behaves as it's a concave function, and it's actually easy to show that it's concave in one-dimentional $\mathbf s$. So I tried to prove it with showing that $ g(t)  $ is concave, where $$  g(t) = SINR (\mathbf s + t\mathbf v)$$ but getting second derivative of this function even with kronecker product gains nothing and I couldn't prove it. So I want to know if there is any idea to help me how to prove its concavtiy?

**edit**: matrix $N$ and $W$ are both PSD and $0 \prec W $. Aslo we have: 
$$
S_{M \times2M-1} = \begin{bmatrix}
    \mathbf s &  0 & \cdots & 0_{M-1} \\
             & \mathbf s &  \\
 &  &  \ddots & \\
    \mathbf 0_{M-1} & \mathbf 0_{M-2} &  & \mathbf s\\
    \end{bmatrix}
$$
for convolution matrix of $ \mathbf s $

Comment: You would have to supply more info, because in the current form it is definitely not always concave (set $W=0$ and $N\succ 0$ and it is a convex quadratic)

Comment: Thank you for comment, I added them in edit.